# Understanding Itô's Lemma proof in Chung Williams

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am studying the following ito lemma proof, however I am having some trouble understading, and it has been a week without figurigh out certain steps. Here is the theorem statement and full proof, scrolling down you can find the question section.

> Theorem 5.1. Let $M$ be a continuous local martingale and $V$ be a continuous process which is locally of bounded variation. Let $f$ be a continuous real-valued function defined on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x, y), \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}(x, y)$, and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x, y)$, exist and are continuous for all $(x, y)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Then a.s., we have for each $t$

> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> f\left(M_{t}, V_{t}\right)-f\left(M_{0}, V_{0}\right)= & \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(M_{s}, V_{s}\right) d M_{s} \\
> & +\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{s}, V_{s}\right) d V_{s} \\
> & +\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{s}, V_{s}\right) d[M]_{s}
> \end{aligned}
> $$

> For clarity, we have put in the time-parameter $s$ in the stochastic integral $\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(M_{s}, V_{s}\right) d M_{s}$. The reader should keep in mind that this integral is defined stochastically, not path-by-path. A suggestive way to write (5.2) is by using differentials:

> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> d f\left(M_{t}, V_{t}\right)= & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(M_{t}, V_{t}\right) d M_{t} \\
> & +\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t}, V_{t}\right) d V_{t}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{t}, V_{t}\right) d[M]_{t} .
> \end{aligned}
> $$

> Of course the rigorous interpretation of (5.3) is the integrated form (5.2). Example. Let $B$ denote a Brownian motion in $I R$ and let $f(x)=x^{2}$. With $M=B$ and $f(x, y)=f(x),(5.3)$ becomes

$$
>d\left(B_{t}\right)^{2}=2 B_{t} d B_{t}+d t
$$

> Formally this suggests $\left(d B_{t}\right)^{2}=d t$. For general $M$ the appropriate formalism is $\left(d M_{t}\right)^{2}=d[M]_{t}$. Heuristically this explains the presence of the additional term in the Itô formula.

> Proof of Theorem 5.1. Since both sides of the equality in (5.2) are continuous processes, it suffices to prove for each $t$ that (5.2) holds a.s. Let $\left\{\pi_{t}^{n}, n \in I N\right\}$ be a sequence of partitions of $[0, t]$ such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \delta \pi_{t}^{n}=0$. We use the same notation for members of $\pi_{t}^{n}$ as in Chapter 4. In particular, we omit the superscript $n$ from $t_{j}^{n}$. Thus,

> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> f\left(M_{t}, V_{t}\right)-f\left(M_{0}, V_{0}\right)=\sum_{j}\{ & f\left(M_{t_{j+1}}, V_{t_{j+1}}\right) \\
> & -f\left(M_{t_{j+1}}, V_{t_{j}}\right) \\
> & \left.+f\left(M_{t_{j+1}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)-f\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)\right\} .
> \end{aligned}
> $$

> By Taylor's theorem, the right side of the equals sign above may be written as:

> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> & \sum_{j}\left\{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)+\varepsilon_{j}^{1}\right)\left(V_{t_{j+1}}-V_{t_{j}}\right) \\
> &+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)\left(M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_{j}}\right) \\
> &\left.+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)+\varepsilon_{j}^{2}\right)\left(M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_{j}}\right)^{2}\right\}
> \end{aligned}
> $$

> where

> $$
> \varepsilon_{j}^{1}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j+1}}, V_{\tau_{j}}\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)
> $$

> and

> $$
> \varepsilon_{j}^{2}=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{\eta_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)-\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)
> $$

> for some random times $\tau_{j}$ and $\eta_{j}$ in $\left[t_{j}, t_{j+1}\right]$. For each $\omega$, the functions $(r, s) \rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{r}, V_{s}\right)(\omega)$ and $(r, s) \rightarrow \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{r}, V_{s}\right)(\omega)$ are uniformly continuous on $[0, t]^{2}$, and hence $\sup _{j}\left|\varepsilon_{j}^{1}(\omega)\right|$ and $\sup _{j}\left|\varepsilon_{j}^{2}(\omega)\right|$ tend to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$. (Note that $\varepsilon_{j}^{1}$ and $\varepsilon_{j}^{2}$ depend on $n$ although the notation does not specifically indicate this because the indices $n$ on the $t_{j}^{n}$ have been suppressed.) From this property of $\varepsilon_{j}^{1}(\omega)$, the continuity of $s \rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{s}, V_{s}\right)(\omega)$, and since $s \rightarrow V_{s}(\omega)$ is of bounded variation on $[0, t]$ for almost every $\omega$, it follows that

$$
>\sum_{j}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)+\varepsilon_{j}^{1}\right)\left(V_{t_{j+1}}-V_{t_{j}}\right) \rightarrow \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{s}, V_{s}\right) d V_{s}
$$

> almost surely as $n \rightarrow \infty$. From the above property of $\varepsilon_{j}^{2}(\omega)$, and since $\sum_{j}\left(M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_{j}}\right)^{2} \rightarrow[M]_{t}$ in pr. as $n \rightarrow \infty$ by Theorem 4.1(ii), it follows that $\sum_{j} \varepsilon_{j}^{2}\left(M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_{j}}\right)^{2} \rightarrow 0$ in pr. as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

> The proof will be completed in two steps. First we prove that when $M$ and $V$ are bounded, the terms in (5.5) involving the $x$-partial derivatives of $f$ converge in pr. to the appropriate terms in (5.2). Then we extend (5.2) to the general case by using a localizing sequence for $M$ and $V$.

> Suppose that $M$ and $V$ are bounded. Then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}$ are bounded on the range of $(M, V)$ and $\mu_{M}$ is a finite measure on $\mathcal{P}$. For each $n$, the process $X^{n}$ defined by

> $$
> X^{n}=\sum_{j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right) 1_{\left(t_{j}, t_{j+1}\right]}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(M_{0}, V_{0}\right) 1_{\{0\}}
> $$

> is predictable and $\left\{X^{n}\right\}$ converges pointwise to $1_{[0, t]} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(M, V)$ on $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \Omega$ and hence by bounded convergence in $\mathcal{L}^{2}$. Then by the isometry,

> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \sum_{j} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)\left(M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_{j}}\right) & =\int X_{s}^{n} d M_{s} \\
> & \rightarrow \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(M_{s}, V_{s}\right) d M_{s}
> \end{aligned}
> $$

> in $L^{2}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Also, by Theorem 4.8 with $Y=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}(M, V)$, we have

$$
>\sum_{j} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)\left(M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_{j}}\right)^{2} \rightarrow \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{s}, V_{s}\right) d[M]_{s}
$$

> in pr. as $n \rightarrow \infty$. It follows that the expression in (5.5) converges in pr. to the right side of (5.2) and hence (5.2) holds a.s. Thus we have proved the theorem when $M$ and $V$ are bounded.

> To extend to the general case, for each $n$ let $\tau_{n}=\inf \{t \geq 0$ : $\left.\left|M_{t}\right| \vee\left|V_{t}\right|>n\right\}$. Then $M^{n}=M \cdot \wedge \tau_{n} 1_{\left\{\tau_{n}>0\right\}}$ and $V^{n}=V \cdot \wedge \tau_{n} 1_{\left\{\tau_{n}>0\right\}}$ are bounded, and it follows from the above that (5.2) holds a.s. with $M^{n}$, $V^{n}$ in place of $M, V$, respectively, and hence holds a.s. with $t \wedge \tau_{n}$ in place of $t$. Then (5.2) follows on letting $n \rightarrow \infty$.

**Question**

My problem starts in the following step: $$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{j}\left\{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)+\varepsilon_{j}^{1}\right)\left(V_{t_{j+1}}-V_{t_{j}}\right) \\
&+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)\left(M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_{j}}\right) \\
&\left.+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)+\varepsilon_{j}^{2}\right)\left(M_{t_{j+1}}-M_{t_{j}}\right)^{2}\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

where

$$
\varepsilon_{j}^{1}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j+1}}, V_{\tau_{j}}\right)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)
$$

and

$$
\varepsilon_{j}^{2}=\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{\eta_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)-\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)
$$

for some random times $\tau_{j}$ and $\eta_{j}$ in $\left[t_{j}, t_{j+1}\right]$.

How is the author applying in this case the Taylor theorem? I noticed that the author is incrementing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(M_{t_j},V_{t_j})$ with and the same for $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(M_{t_j},V_{t_j})$ with $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ respectively.But why does the author use  $\tau_{j}$ and $\eta_{j}$ instead of $t_j$? I think the latter would resume the standard Taylor expansion formula.

**For each $\omega$, the functions $(r, s) \rightarrow \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{r}, V_{s}\right)(\omega)$ and $(r, s) \rightarrow \frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}\left(M_{r}, V_{s}\right)(\omega)$ are uniformly continuous on $[0, t]^{2}$, and hence $\sup _{j}\left|\varepsilon_{j}^{1}(\omega)\right|$ and $\sup _{j}\left|\varepsilon_{j}^{2}(\omega)\right|$ tend to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$.**

The partial derivative of $f$ is assumed to be continuous but how does he infer the partial derivatives, hence $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ are uniformly continuous? That does not seem straightforward to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authors use a version of Taylor formula, called Taylor-Lagrange formula. It says, for a differentiable function $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ we have that, for $a,b$ two fixed real numbers, there exists $\xi\in (a,b)$ such that

$$g(a)=g(b)+g'(\xi)(a-b)$$
or at order $2$
$$g(a)=g(b)+g'(b)(a-b)+\frac{1}{2}g''(\xi)(a-b)^2.$$
If I apply this to $f(M_{t_{j+1}},V_{t_{j+1}})-f(M_{t_{j+1}},V_{t_{j}})$ in the second variable, I get that there exists $\xi_j\in(V_{t_{j+1}},V_{t_{j}})$ (or $(V_{t_j},V_{t_{j+1}})$ depending on how they arrange) such that
$$
f(M_{t_{j+1}},V_{t_{j+1}})-f(M_{t_{j+1}},V_{t_{j}})=\frac{\partial f}{\partial_y}f(M_{t_{j+1}},\xi_j)(V_{t_{j+1}}-V_{t_j})
$$
but because $V$ is continuous, I can find rather than $\xi_j$ a time $\tau_j\in(t_j,t_{j+1})$ such that $\xi_j=V_{\tau_j}$. Of course, since $V$ is random, so do $\tau_j$. This, gives
$$
f(M_{t_{j+1}},V_{t_{j+1}})-f(M_{t_{j+1}},V_{t_{j}})=\frac{\partial f}{\partial_y}f(M_{t_{j+1}},V_{\tau_j})(V_{t_{j+1}}-V_{t_j}).
$$
For the part concerning, we need the order $2$, because $M$ is not of finite variation but of finite quadratic variation.

Concerning your second question, the function, for almost all $\omega$,
$$
(s,r)\to\frac{\partial f}{\partial_y}(M_{s},V_{r})(\omega)
$$
is continuous on the compact $[0,t]$, thus it is uniformly continuous (Heine Thm). Continuity, gives that, because $V_{t_j}<V_{\tau_j}<V_{t_{j+1}}$ (or $ V_{t_{j+1}}<V_{\tau_j}<V_{t_{j}})$, for almost all $\omega$
$$
\varepsilon_j^1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j+1}}, V_{\tau_{j}}\right)(\omega)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)(\omega)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0,
$$
but for any $j$
$$
\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j+1}}, V_{\tau_{j}}\right)(\omega)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)(\omega)\right|\leq \sup_{\underset{\scriptstyle|r-v|<\delta_n}{|s-u|<\delta_n}} \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{s}, V_{r}\right)(\omega)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{u}, V_{v}\right)(\omega)\right|,
$$
where $\delta_n=\sup_j|t_{j+1}-t_j|$. So
$$
\sup_{j}\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j+1}}, V_{\tau_{j}}\right)(\omega)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{t_{j}}, V_{t_{j}}\right)(\omega)\right|\leq \sup_{\underset{\scriptstyle|r-v|<\delta_n}{|s-u|<\delta_n}} \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{s}, V_{r}\right)(\omega)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{u}, V_{v}\right)(\omega)\right|
$$
but, uniform continuity gives
$$
\sup_{\underset{\scriptstyle|r-v|<\delta_n}{|s-u|<\delta_n}} \left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{s}, V_{r}\right)(\omega)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\left(M_{u}, V_{v}\right)(\omega)\right|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.
$$
It is similar for the $\varepsilon^2$'s.